# I am trying to get custom date to pass to PayPal

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, paypal

I am trying to get this line of product info here to pass into PayPal form using the custom varible `<input type="hidden" name="custom"  value="SansburyTech|Purchase of a ToolCart|Dewalt Roller|SKU:164604646|Cost:163.50">` but its not happening?

Is there something I am doing wrong or overlooking? Here on [PayPalDocs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) it says specifically: *The following are pass-through variables:* **custom** or **item_number** or **item_number_x** or **invoice**

Here is my complete HTML Paypal form as an example;

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin:0;padding:0;" target="PayPal">
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Toolcart">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Dewalt Roller">
          <input
            type="hidden"
            name="custom"
            value="SansburyTech|Purchase of a ToolCart|Dewalt Roller|SKU:164604646|Cost:163.50">
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="244.50">
          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
          <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://toolcart.info/pickup">
          <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
          <input type="image" src="/wp-content/themes/toolcart-theme/images/paypal.png" class="img-fluid" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
          <img border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
```

Will be incredibly grateful for any answers!
~ Thank-you!

Comment: It's likely because you have symbols in your `custom` value like pipes and colons. I suggest you Base64-encode it to be safe. (But you're fine w.r.t. length limit, that's 255 chars and your value is only 76).

Comment: How are you reading the variables back out, exactly? (i.e. where is it not working?) Please post your PHP code that processes IPNs or other PayPal messages.

Comment: what do you mean by **but its not happening** ? Please note that custom field value is used in the IPN callback.

Comment: I am only interested in getting that custom field in an email which then gets passed to Zapier and parsed out into Quickbooks, but for some reason that line doesn't get passed into the PayPal transaction email?

Comment: @KenLee What I meant its not passing it into my PayPal email or Transaction within PayPal. Maybe I should use "invoice" instead or is that only for IPN as well - not using IPN right now too complicated for me.

Comment: @ShrockCo The `custom` value is not included in any PayPal-generated emails. It only appears in IPN messages and (I think?) when users get redirected back to your site. Also, Zapier is probably not the best tool to automate PayPal with (nothing bad about Zapier, it's just that PayPal is just _so awful_ that you always end-up having to write manual code yourself).

Comment: @Dai Yes I noticed that yesterday, that its not in the emails but shows up in the transactions in PayPal just fine, not sure how I missed that earlier - Thanks everyone for all your help -- its much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer (for that sweet sweet karma).

---

The OP was looking for the `custom` variable to appear in the PayPal-generated e-mail messages that get sent back to the merchant account-holder (or to the customer). This won't work because PayPal does not include the `custom` variable in any e-mail messages: it's only included in IPN messages.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best solution is to pass only a unique identifier and store the rest in own your database.

But if you must pass multiple values in the arbitrary `custom` field, the pipes in your example seem problematic.  Use base64 encoding or a different delimiter--JSON format is a common choice here, then you can simply decode it into an array when receiving the IPN.